# Can I dynamically add a custom serializer to Hazelcast cluster?

Tags: serialization, hazelcast

I would prefer to serialize a new data objects without restarting production cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind that you don't have to do a full restart, you can do a rolling restart (restart members one by one and add the new class) before you start working on the newly added object.

On the other hand, there's user code deployment feature (however this is offered in the enterprise edition) that enables to load classes to the cluster from members/clients: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.3/manual/html-single/index.html#member-user-code-deployment-beta

Comment: Yes, rolling restart is the answer.

Comment: One day java will be able to load modules dynamically and this answer will be changed.